# Cronjob error : Unmatched ". What does this mean?

Tags: unix, cron

I ran an automatic task via cronjob. Previously it was working well, however, at some point, the cronjob won't run the task anymore.

also, when I tried to rerun the task, I got an error email that says `Unmatched ".`

What is happening?

Comment: We can't tell without seeing the command that fails.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, this usually happens because of improper usage of characters like \" or special char '$' etc. It would be easier to debug if code snippet can be shared. Also which shell is being used.